# Add border to padding

Tags: css, border, padding

I have a div, padding set to 50px both left and right.

[image: Padding border?]

Is it possible to add the purple border?

I cannot add code to the HTML, this should be done with pure css if possible. I tried to trick this with border-image and adding gradients but I could only add like this:

```
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;

  border-top: 5px solid black;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 50px, purple 0%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}

<div>Content</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u7zq0amc/1/

Comment: couldn't you use a `margin` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo element instead:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: grey;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:20px;
}
div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:5px;
  top:-5px;
  right:50px;
  left:50px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>Content</div>
```